# How can I run a standalone hiveserver2 with internal authentication?

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I have Datastax DSE (4.5) cluster that uses internal authentation (using `org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator`). Is it possible for me to [run a standalone hiveserver2](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaHivStrtSvr.html?scroll=anaHivStrtSvr__hiveserver2)? How? So far I haven't found anything about this in the Datastax documentation. [This page](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/sec/secIntrnlAuth.html?scroll=secItrnlAuth__using-the-command-line) does not have an example of running a hiveserver2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start dse hive --service hiveserver2 --hiveconf cassandra.username=cassandra --hiveconf cassandra.password=cassandra

Then use beeline to connect to it

beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000?cassandra.username=cassandra;cassandra.password=cassandra org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver